# ESLint error in Vue template concerning JSX

Tags: vue.js, jsx, eslint

I have a vue single file component where, the template section looks like this

```
<template>
   <Card>
      /// rest of template here ///
   </Card>
</template>
```

`Card` is an imported Vue component.

For some reason, I don't understand, ESLint in VSCode underlines the  element with the red line and is warning me that `Card cannot be used as a JSX component`. I have installed and configured eslint with vue with every online tutorial I could find and the warning won't go away.

Any ideas on what should I configure to remove this stupid warning?

Comment: The code builds and runs correctly. I DON'T use vue-cli. I configure everything from scratch. I just get a warning about JSX in a place (template) where JSX doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the immediate problem, add `"jsx": "preserve"` to your `tsconfig.json` file.

For a more permanent solution, you can also extend the recommended Vue-based typescript settings in your `tsconfig.json` by adding:

`"extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json"`